# Python Webkit-Browser: Problems on attaching the developer-toolbar

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, glade

I want to dive in Python by building a simple browser-application. I've mad a minimalistic webkitbrowser with a tutorial and now want to extend the program, but I'm stuck at some tiny problems I cannot solve.

---

Python 3.3.3
using Glade for the UI

The first step is to simply add a second scrolledWindow in which the developer-tools should load, immediately.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/29e19515626bd7d37f14) is my .ui-file so far, and this is the python-code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit    

UI_FILE = "browser.ui"    

class Browser:
    """A simple Webkit-Browser in GTK+"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(UI_FILE)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        self.back = self.builder.get_object("back")
        self.forward = self.builder.get_object("forward")
        self.adress = self.builder.get_object("adress")

        self.webview = WebKit.WebView()
        scrolled_window = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindow")
        scrolled_window.add(self.webview)

        self.settings = WebKit.WebSettings()
        self.settings.set_property('enable-developer-extras', True)

        self.webview.set_settings(self.settings)

        self.devtools = WebKit.WebInspector()
        scrolled_window_dev = self.builder.get_object("scrolledwindowDev")
        scrolled_window_dev.add(self.devtools)

                         ^^^^^

        self.webview.connect("title-changed", self.on_title_changed)

        self.window = self.builder.get_object("window")
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_title_changed(self, webview, frame, title):
        self.window.set_title(title)

    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        if button.get_stock_id() == Gtk.STOCK_GO_FORWARD:
            self.webview.go_forward()
        elif button.get_stock_id() == Gtk.STOCK_GO_BACK:
            self.webview.go_back()

    def on_entry_activate(self, widget):
        url = widget.get_text()
        if not "http://" in url:
            url = "http://"+url
        self.webview.load_uri(url)

    def destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()


def main():
    app = Browser()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the error

> TypeError: argument widget: Expected Gtk.Widget, but got
>   gi.repository.WebKit.WebInspector

Okay, this is stated in the [reference](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebInspector.html#WebKitWebInspector.object-hierarchy) of Webkit, that WebInspector is a GObject and not a GtkWidget. But I don't know what to do now.

So, can I make a GtkWidget from a GObject (if yes - how) or should I attach the dev-tools in a complete different way?

Answer (score 0):

The inspector, as you noted, isn't a widget. It's a web page, so you need to create another webview for it. You do this by getting `self.window.props.web_inspector` (don't create a new inspector) and connecting to its `inspect-web-view` signal. Inside that signal handler, you need to create a new webview, add that webview to a window or wherever you want to display it, and return it.

You'll probably also want to handle the `show-window`, `attach-window`, `detach-window`, and `close-window` signals.

More documentation here: [`inspect-web-view`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/WebKitWebInspector.html#WebKitWebInspector-inspect-web-view)

Answer (score 0):

Example of running Inspector in separate window. Webkit-gtk.

This gist without many signals connected.

https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/53518825b2a8a50dd1695c69ee5058cc